# Refreshing auth token with AppAuth library on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, gmail-api, appauth

I'm using the [AppAuth library](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS) to get an access token for the Gmail API. I've successfully been able to create an Auth Session, and use the retrieved token to later fetch the emails.

In my `AppDelegate` I have two variables:

```
var currentAuthorizationFlow: OIDExternalUserAgentSession?
var authState: OIDAuthState?
```

In my `SignInViewController`, I have the following code for performing the authorization flow:

```
@objc func startAuthFlow() {
    
    Analytics.logEvent("auth_started", parameters: nil)
    
    let authorizationEndpoint = URL(string: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth")!
    let tokenEndpoint = URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token")!
    let configuration = OIDServiceConfiguration(authorizationEndpoint: authorizationEndpoint,
                                                tokenEndpoint: tokenEndpoint)
    let kRedirectURI: String = "com.googleusercontent.apps.someNumber:/oauthredirect";
    
    guard let redirectURI = URL(string: kRedirectURI) else {
        return
    }
    
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    // builds authentication request
    let request = OIDAuthorizationRequest(configuration: configuration,
                                          clientId: "myID",
                                          clientSecret: nil,
                                          scopes: ["https://mail.google.com/"],
                                          redirectURL: redirectURI,
                                          responseType: OIDResponseTypeCode,
                                          additionalParameters: nil)
    

    
    // performs authentication request
    print("Initiating authorization request with scope: \(request.scope ?? "nil")")
            
    appDelegate.currentAuthorizationFlow =
        OIDAuthState.authState(byPresenting: request, presenting: self) { authState, error in
                if let authState = authState {

                print("Got authorization tokens. Access token: " +
                        "\(authState.lastTokenResponse?.accessToken ?? "nil")")
               A0SimpleKeychain().setString((authState.lastTokenResponse?.accessToken)!, forKey: "auth0-user-jwt")
                A0SimpleKeychain().setString((authState.lastTokenResponse?.refreshToken)!, forKey: "auth0-user-jwt-refresh")

                EmailFetcher.shared.setupEmailSession(token: (authState.lastTokenResponse?.accessToken)!)
                

            } else {
              
                print("Authorization error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
            }
        }
}
```

I then successfully save the token and the refresh token.

I saw that there was a `tokenRefreshRequest()` method for `OIDAuthState`, but my understanding is that you would need to pass in the refresh token to get a new, fresh token, correct? What's the missing piece to implementing this with AppAuth?

Answer (score 4):

To refresh an access token you use a 'refresh token grant' message with arguments similar to this:

```
let request = OIDTokenRequest(
    configuration: self.metadata!,
    grantType: OIDGrantTypeRefreshToken,
    authorizationCode: nil,
    redirectURL: nil,
    clientID: self.configuration.clientId,
    clientSecret: nil,
    scope: nil,
    refreshToken: tokenData!.refreshToken!,
    codeVerifier: nil,
    additionalParameters: nil)

OIDAuthorizationService.perform(request) { tokenResponse, error in ...
```

Note that I'm not using the AuthState class in my sample, since I wanted to store tokens encrypted in the iOS keychain, so your code may be a little different. For something to compare against, you can run the code sample from by blog:

- [Code Sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.ios)
- [Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2020/02/22/ios-code-sample-overview/)

Comment: So when a refresh token is used, does the app logs out after a certain time and prompts the user to sign in again with username and password every time?..

Comment: Yes - access token expires frequently. eg every 30 minutes, refresh token represents the user session time, which might be 2 hours, 24 hours, 1 week or whatever you prefer. When the RT expires. the user must reauthenticate.

Answer (score 1):

Create an authState from auth token or directly save authstate model into key chain then access latest refresh token using below methods.
authState

```
authState.performAction { (accessToken, authToken, error) in
        guard let err = error else {return} 
        print("updated refresh token is : \(accessToken)")
     }
```